# Change the row color of Repeatbox

Tags: javascript, mobile, smartface.io

Is there a way to change row color of `repeatbox` object in smartface app studio when the item selected or touched? Also how can we do that dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in onRowRender event of RepeatBox;

```
this.fillColor = ((e.rowIndex % 2)=== 0 ? "#ECECEC" : "#FFFFFF");
```

Smartface.io Team

Comment: or `this.fillColor = ((e.rowIndex % 2)=== 0 ? "blue" : "yellow"`

Answer (score 0):

if you want it on selected, you can use repeatbox active item properties. You can add what u want to row with this Activeitem. For use, u have to tick property or dynamicly assigne true the "use active item" property. And add your items to activeItem row.